# How to program an SSD1322 display?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega2560

I'm new to programming. I would like to change the characters on an SSD1322 OLED display. Here are the photos.

Is this possible with an Arduino Uno? Is the program of the display in the display or in the Mega 2560?

Thanks for your help!

[image: 2560]
[image: SSD1322]
[image: overview]

Comment: An SSD1322 is just a graphical OLED display, like the SSD1306 and many others. It just displays what it's sent. Whatever that thing is it's plugged in to is what is generating the graphics that are being displayed.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer,
so if I understand the program that manages the display is on the pcb or there is the 2560?

Comment: It's whatever the display is plugged into. It may be that 2560, but I don't know what that board is, so can't comment.

Comment: on the 2560 card there is an ISP connector
http://liedson.fr/1.jpg
is it possible to connect an arduino uno to read the program that is in the 2560?

Comment: no, it is most likely copy protected

Comment: yes that is possible, but I have a second blank pcb without a program,
I just wanted help with the procedure.
must it connect the pcb 2560 by the IPS with an arduino uno?

I can also pay the person who will take the time to help me work on it!